# List of objects where the object contains an array - how to use LINQ to search through all objects for a value in that array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

So I have a list of objects and the object class itself contains an array that holds multiple values. How can I search through all of the objects in the lists' arrays to look for that value?

Example:

```
[
{
    "ObjArray": ["1234", 123"],
    "Property1": "60",
    "Property2": "64"
},
{
    "ObjArray": ["4321", 321"],
    "Property1": "112",
    "Property2": "22"
},
{
    "ObjArray": ["9999"],
    "Property1": "2",
    "Property2": "2"
}
]
```

And I want to look for "9999" in all of the "ObjArray"s. How can I do that with LINQ?

### **EDIT**

As Habib pointed out, I just needed a simple Contains clause. Working code looks like this:

```
var result = mainList.Where(r => r.ObjArray != null && r.ObjArray.Contains("9999", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var query = mainList.Where(r => r.ObjArray.Contains("9999"));
```

Or

```
var query = mainList.Where(r => r.ObjArray.Any(o => o == "9999"));
```

*(Aside from that, your JSON appears invalid, Second value in the array needs a starting double quote)*

```
["1234", 123"]
       //^^
```

Comment: Yup this did it! Very simple when I see it. Thank you!

Also I wrote that JSON on the fly, so the real JSON is valid. Nice catch though ;)

Comment: Agree with this answer but I would have used var result instead of var query to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @YoungBob, it is still a query, it hasn't been evaluated yet :)